# ReactJS: passing down a simple object prop to a component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and there are 2 problems with my simple demo: firstly I cannot seem to pass an object prop to a component (hence `{obj.testKey}` should render otherwise); secondly I cannot seem to get the `{info}` to render despite it being used exactly the same way as with the `title` prop.

How can I get the `{obj.testKey}` and `{info}` to render? I'm assuming I'm missing something extremely obvious as this seems basic.

Here's the demo component:

```
import React from "react";

const TestComponent = ({ title }, { info }, { obj }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>test paragraph from component</p>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <div>
        efer {info} {obj.testKey}
      </div>
      {console.log("info", info)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

And the main app:

```
import React from "react";
import TestComponent from "./test-component";

const DemoComponent = () => {
  return <p>hello!</p>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>test</p>
      <DemoComponent />
      <TestComponent
        title="title test"
        info="info test"
        obj={ "testKey": "value" }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqpkc5?file=src%2FApp.js) demo for convenience.

Also, why do I have to destructure the props `{ title }, { info }, { obj }`? This feels like a suboptimal way.

Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an object as a prop you need two sets of curly braces.

```
<MyComponent foo={{ key: value }} />
```

The first `{}` says to run whatever code is in there and return the result as the property value. The second `{}` create an object literal to return.

That means you can change your component invocation to:

```
  <TestComponent
    title="title test"
    info="info test"
    obj={{ "testKey": "value" }}
  />
```

---

On your component destructuring props, your example in the question has different syntax `({ title }, { info }, { obj })` than the one you linked on stackblitz `({ title, info, obj })`. But the one on stackblitz is the correct one.

A component receives its props as a single argument that is a single object with one property for each each prop. Using the `({ a, b, c })` syntax as the arguments of a functional component allows you pull out those props into their own local variables which is very handy and simple.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is because of incorrect destructuring. The correct way will look like

```
const TestComponent = ({ title, info,  obj }) => {
...
}
```

The second is because you have to pass an object as a parameter with two `{}` like this `{{testKey: "value"}}`

```
<TestComponent   
   title="title test"
   info="info test"
   obj={{ testKey: "value" }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you react function component receives only one variable `props`, you should destructure as:

```
const TestComponent = ({ title, info,  obj }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>test paragraph from component</p>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <div>
        efer {info} {obj.testKey}
      </div>
      {console.log("info", info)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

plus your obj param should be passed down as `obj={ { testKey: "value" } }` if you want to provide an object to it.